# C++ Reading "Already Formatted" Array from file into an Int Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, ifstream, getline

So I open an File with a bunch of parameters followed by integers that read fine; but a single parameter in the file needs to be read into an ARRAY instead and is formatted in plain-text as such:

```
Demand = [6907,14342,36857,40961,61129,69578,72905,91977,93969,97336];
```

assuming I already have this line read into a string named "line"; how would I pull those numbers into an array named "Demand[]"?

*edit: the actual numbers are just examples and are not important*

Comment: search for the `[` and `]` delimiter and concatenate each number. Then add them to an `std::vector`. You could also use `RegEx` for parsing, but looks like a bit of an overkill.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overkill" when referring to RegEx?

Comment: Flex, regex, iterating, find/substr, etc. Lots of ways many of which are already detailed on SO.

Comment: "overkill" is subjected to my own experience. If your file format is as simple as you state, a handwritten parser will not require more than 5-10 lines of code. In my experience, the code will be faster to write, faster to run, and easier to debug.

If your file format is more complicated, I would go for RegEx: it can be turn into a more forgiving parser easier; it can be adapted for new formats easier.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to parse a string containing a list of items try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    const char *s="Demand = [6907,14342,36857,40961,61129,69578,72905,91977,93969,97336];";
    int count=0,Demand[20];
    char *pointer=strchr(s,'[');
    while(pointer && *pointer++!=']')
        Demand[count++]=strtol(pointer,&pointer,10);
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i) printf("%d ",Demand[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

when the while loop starts count is 0 and pointer is pointing to the character before the start of the next integer (either , or [ in this case)  The while loop moves pointer to the start of the integer and then strtol moves pointer to the end of the integer (to the , or ] depending) and count is incremented as part of saving the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the necessary part of the data i.e. 6907,14342,36857,40961,61129,69578,72905,91977,93969,97336 into a temporary string using substr function.
Replace all commas in the temporary string with space .
Store the temporary string to a stringstream object. 
Then read the space separated numbers from the stringstream object as you would read from cin and store it in a vector or array of your choice.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line="Demand = [6907,14342,36857,40961,61129,69578,72905,91977,93969,97336]";
    string temp=line.substr(10,line.length()-(10+1));//Assuming 10 is the index of the first number  i.e. 6907 (here) and subtracting the number of characters skipped in the begining + ']' (10+1)
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length();++i)
        if(temp[i]==',')//Check if it is a comma
            temp[i]=' ';//Replace all commas with space
    vector<int> arr;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<temp;//Store the string to a stringstream object
    int num;
    while(ss>>num)//Check whether stringstream has any remaining data
        arr.push_back(num);//If data is obtained from stringstream insert it to the integer vector
    for(i=0;i<arr.size();++i)
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;//Output the vector data
}
```